# How to provide administrative access to windows application without UAC

Tags: vb.net, privileges, uac, administrator

I'm building a windows application from Visual Studio - VB.NET. This application administrative privileges from the operating system. This is completely fine with the PCs which got the administrative privileges. But for the PCs which doesn't have administrative privileges the UAC prompts.
I tried so many things to embed administrative access to the application but non of them success.
Please guide me to make this success
Thanks

Comment: Why would you think that you could get administrative access without the approval of an administrator?

Comment: This application install in computers connected with the domain environment. Once I build the EXE, administrator install this application in every computer. once it opened it always ask for the administrator Username and the password. Once the administrator enters the password and restart the PC, again it asks. I want to make Admin to enter the password once and runs forever. Like windows keep the application under administrator apps.

Comment: What your describing isn't the norm.  Either there is something in your software that is doing something it probably shouldn't or there is some sort of over zealous environmentally security policy in place on the domain.  Perhaps start with trying to nail down exactly what in your software is requiring the elevated permissions

Comment: What does your program do that requires administrative permissions to run?